# In Web application, could not load type? asp .net?

Tags: asp.net

In web applicaiton, when i am running the asp.net project i am getting the error like :

```
Could not load type 'Com.ajSolutions.CosmacCRM.Web.EmpInserting'.
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmpInserting.aspx.cs" Inherits="Com.ajSolutions.CosmacCRM.Web.EmpInserting" %>
```

can you help me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often a result of the compiled code not being found by the runtime.

The DLL may be missing.  Or if it's compiled on the fly, the code itself may be missing.  Or maybe the type itself doesn't exist in the code (possibly renamed or moved to a different namespace).